# MYSQL : match and remove matched word from string

Tags: mysql

I have to remove word from string when matched found

let's see

**My input string is**

### 'KENOX ROAD'

**Table of words from with match perform**

1. STREET
2. DRIVE
3. ROAD

   ### 4. DRIVE WAY

### Out string should be :

**KENOX**

I am using vb.net for this windows form application.I am getting input string from textbox and on a button click i have to check for matches which are coming from database and remove matched words.
current solution is :

```
  Dim strStreetName As String = txtHStreet.Text
    For Each wordToRemove As DataRow In dsAbbreviation.Tables(0).Rows

        If strStreetName.Contains(wordToRemove.Item("NAME")) Then
            strStreetName = strStreetName.Replace(wordToRemove.Item("NAME"), "")

            Exit For
        End If
    Next
```

but, I am looking for database side solution.

Comment: What have you tried so far? What programming/scripting language are you using? Are you wanting to save the changes back to the database or are you simply displaying the text to a user? If you update your question to include this information, you are more likely to get an answer.

Answer (score 0):

I *think* the following will work:

```
set @phrase = 'KENOX ROAD';

set @phrase = concat(' ', phrase, ' ')

select @phrase := replace(@phrase, concat(' ', w.word, ' '), ' '))
from words w;

set @phrase = trim(@phrase);
```

Your problem is a bit tricky because you seem to want the words to be identified and (unfortunately) MySQL does not have regex replace functionality.  The above adds delimiters at the beginning and end and then does the replacement.  Using variables like this is not a favorite approach, but I think it will work in this case.

Answer (score 0):

MariaDB starts with 10.0.5 with REGEX - PCRE Regular Expressions

[Mariadb REGEX Manual](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/pcre/)

Answer (score 0):

MySQL does not natively support regexp replace. If you want to update an existing table you can try with something like this:

```
UPDATE
  streets s INNER JOIN words w
  ON INSTR(CONCAT(' ', s.name, ' '), CONCAT(' ', w.word, ' '))>0
SET
  s.name = TRIM(
    REPLACE(CONCAT(' ', s.name, ' '), CONCAT(' ', w.word, ' '), ' ')
  );
```

and if you want to match and replace multiple words you have to re-run this update query until it doesn't find any more match. Please see a fiddle [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/79500/1). Not too clean, but it should do its work.

If you just want a SELECT, and you want it to support multiple words replace, I think there's no solution unless you use a programming language.